# How to reset anonymous function

Tags: javascript

The first button is working fine. When I click on it id adds one to the preceding value. The second button should reset to `0`. This is also working, but when I click on the first button again, it increments the old (preceding) value:

- contador() value -> 1
- contador() value -> 2
- contador() value -> 3
- reset() value -> 0
- contador() value -> 4

```js
 var sumar = (function() {
   var contador = 0;
   return function() {
     return contador += 1;
   }
 })();

 function llamar() {
   document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = sumar();
 }

 function reset() {
   document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = 0;

 }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="llamar()">contar</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<p id="valor">0</p>
```

Comment: Why using anonymouse function for this simple thing? however, you need to set contador to zero, not innerHTML

Comment: you are not setting the value of "contador" variable. simply setting the value of innerHTML doesn't have any effect over the variable.

Comment: i have tried contador = 0 ; but it doesnt works

Comment: `contador` is a private variable. In your code you can't reset the _local_ variable value. `contador = 0` creates another variable, a global variable and local variables overshadow global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **increment** and **reset** in **one** function, because you need access to the **private** variable from both of the functions:

```js
var makeCounter = function() {
  var count = 0; // Private variable
  return {
    increment: function() {
      return count += 1;
    },
    reset: function() {
      count = 0;
      return count;
    }
  }
}

var c = makeCounter();

function llamar() {
  document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = c.increment();
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = c.reset();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="llamar()">contar</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<p id="valor">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot currently do this with your setup, if you alter it slightly, however...

```
var sumar, resetContador;
(function() {
    var contador = 0;
    sumar = function() { return contador++; }
    resetContador = function() { contador = 0; return contador; }
})();

var reset = function () { document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = resetContador(); };
```

edit: I should explain, you cannot do this because you've enclosed contador into a scope that is not accessible from the outside, so to fix that you must define both the increment and reset functions within the closure that defines the contador variable, this will allow multiple functions to alter the value of the 'private' contador variable

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is setting the text of 'valor' to 0. When you hit the button to increment it, contador is still going to be at whatever you left it at, so it's going to just increment its value and display that. I'm not sure why you're using an anonymous function, but you need a way to change the actual value of contador. You can make it a global variable perhaps, but there are better ways to structure this code.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have shown ways to restructure the code so that `llamar` and `reset` access the same counter inside an anonymous function. Storing the count in a [closure](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/what-is-a-closure) like this does, however, seem more complicated than necessary.

An OOP approach would be to create an object holding the count as a property value with additional methods to increment, reset or read the count value. Such an object would not make the count value private in any way.

Alternatively you could even use the HTML element for counting purposes:

```
function llamar(){
  var contador = document.getElementById("valor");
  contador.innerHTML = + contador.innerHTML + 1;
}

function reset(){
  document.getElementById("valor").innerHTML = 0;
}
```